# Variable loses some value when used in Ajax API Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an issue that causes my variable `tempid` to lose some of its values when put into the second API call.  As you can see from my image, if I log the variable to console (`console.log(tempid)`) it shows just fine. However, as soon as I place it in an API call it has some of the value but not all. Could you please help me by explaining why this would happen?

[image: console example]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Template/GetTemplates?classId=7ac62bd4-8fce-a150-3b40-16a39a61383d",
        async:true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

        
$(data).each(function (data) {

  if (this.Name === "Name of Template"){
var tempid = this.Id
console.log (tempid)
var tempurl = "/api/V3/Projection/CreateProjectionByTemplate?id=" + tempid + "&createdById=703853d4-ffc4-fce3-3034-0b838d40c385"
    $.ajax({
        url: tempurl,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
 }
        });

  }
});
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the console is just showing a shortened version of the URL and happened to cut off part of the tempid. Thank you